# Set array inside looping doesn't work javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i try to set value of array inside multiple looping , but when i try to get index of first looping, i just get the last one.

example like this

```
start_date = 1;
end_date = 4;
parent = [];
item = [
{item : 1},
{item : 2},
{item : 3} 
];

for(i = start_date;i <= end_date;i++){
   for(x = 0; x < item.length; x++){
       item[x].parent = i;
   }
parent.push(item)
}
```

but the output always 4,

```
parent = [
    [
      {item : 1,parent : 1},
      {item : 2,parent : 1},
      {item : 3,parent : 1},
    ],
    [
      {item : 1,parent : 2},
      {item : 2,parent : 2},
      {item : 3,parent : 2},
    ],
    [
      {item : 1,parent : 3},
      {item : 2,parent : 3},
      {item : 3,parent : 3},
    ],
    [
      {item : 1,parent : 4},
      {item : 2,parent : 4},
      {item : 3,parent : 4},
    ],
]
```

i want the output like

sorry for my bad english

Comment: expected output ?

Comment: This is because you loop over the same array 4 times, and it gets overwritten 3 times. So it will have had the numbers 1-4 in there but since it gets overwritten, only 4 will be shown to you

Comment: You are overriding the value every iteration, so it's normal you get `4`. What output do you expect?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: Sorry ArunKumaresh, Nina Scholz, TechnoCrat , i was updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the Elements in the Array in the first Iteratiton to 1, in the second to 2 ... and in the last to 4.

So the ouput is correct, what are you trying to achieve?

---

Edit after question Update:

Your Problem is, that you you always reference in all your array the same object. But this object is overwritten each time you call `item[x].parent = i` so you have to create foreaach Element in the Array an object on it's own.

```js
start_date = 1;
end_date = 4;
parent = [];
item = [
{item : 1},
{item : 2},
{item : 3} 
];

for(i = start_date;i <= end_date;i++){
   var temp = [];
   for(x = 0; x < item.length; x++){
   temp[x] = {};
   temp[x].item = item[x].item;
   temp[x].parent = i
   }
parent.push(temp)
}
```

Comment: i was updated my question

Comment: have a look at my updated answer